# Randomize five colors and assign them to nine elements' background. Make sure all five colors are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting, random

I have an array of five colors:

`var colors = ['#ff988a', '#51caf3', '#7ddb7f', '#ffce6e', '#bdb3f6'];`

And nine elements - let's call them *bubbles*:

`var bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');`

I need to randomly define a background color for each bubble, and make sure all five colors are used - meaning there can't be only three or four colors for nine bubbles.

The function that generates random colors is:

```
function getRandomColor(colors) {
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

And I have another function that assigns background colors for the bubbles, yet not able to make sure all the colors are used:

```
function changeColors(elements, colors) {
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var randomColor = getRandomColor(colors);
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
  }
}
```

There is a button that switches colors of the bubbles, so whenever it is clicked, function `changeColors` is triggered. Imagine there is this PM (a pretty one, to be fair) who demands every switch brings all five colors and no less.

**Bear in mind that: the bubbles are *absolutely positioned* so there will not be apparent orders, which means determining the color of sibling bubbles in HTML orders makes no sense, I guess.**

Comment: To whoever unvoted the question right after I posted it - uncool, man, you didn't read it through and picture the scenario. It is not a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could start by defining an array that contains an as equal as possible number of all colors:

```
var colorsToUse = Array.apply(null, { length: bubbles.length })
                       .map(function(_,i) { return colors[i%colors.length]; });
```

From there, you could simply pick a color at random, from the list of available colors:

```
 bubbles.forEach(function(bubble) {
    // get a random index, from the list of available colors
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorsToUse.length);

    // get the color at that index, and remove it from the collection
    var bubbleColor = colorsToUse.splice(index, 1);

    // set bubble color to bubbleColor
 });
```

This was the simplest implementation I could think of which would guarantee all colors to be used, given that the number of bubbles is at least equal to the number of colors. It does mean, however, that you will never have three bubbles of one color, but only one of another, for instance. If you want that amount of variation in appearance, `colorsToUse` could be adjusted to start out by being a duplicate of `color`, and then fetching remaining colors at random, rather than starting over from index 0, as `i%colors.length` would imply.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrpk4Lf8/)